# Book translation data format

Tags: vim, nlp, translation, file-format

I'm thinking of translating a book from English to my native language. I can translate just fine, and I'm happy with `vim` as a text editor. My problem is that I'd like to somehow preserve the semantics, i.e. which parts of my translation correspond to the original.

I could basically create a simple XML-based markup language, that'd look something like

```
<book>
  <chapter>
    <paragraph>
      <sentence>
        <original>This is an example sentence.</original>
        <translation lang="fi">Tämä on esimerkkilause.</translation>
      </sentence>
    </paragraph>
  </chapter>
</book>
```

Now, that would probably have its benefits but I don't think editing that would be very fun.

Another possibility that I can think of would be to keep the original and translation in separate files. If I add a newline after each translation chunk and keep line numbering consistent, editing would be easy and I'd be able to programmatically match the original and translation.

```
original.txt:
  This is an example sentence.
  In this format editing is easy.

translation-fi.txt:
  Tämä on esimerkkilause.
  Tässä muodossa muokkaaminen on helppoa.
```

However, this doesn't seem very robust. It would be easy to mess up. Probably someone has better ideas. Thus the question:

**What would be the best data format for making a book translation with a text editor?**

EDIT: added tag `vim`, since I'd prefer to do this with vim and believe that some vim guru might have ideas.

EDIT2: started a bounty on this. I'm currently leaning to the second idea I describe, but I hope to get something about as easy to edit (and quite easy to implement) but more robust.

Comment: Note that I have *text editor* mentioned in the question on purpose. I need a usable editing interface. I'm open to all suggestions (non-text editor based too), as long as they don't require a great effort to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thought: if you keep each translatable chunk (one or more sentences) in its own line, vim's option `scrollbind`, `cursorbind` and a simple vertical split would help you keeping the chunks "synchronized". It looks very much like to what vimdiff does by default. The files should then have the same amount of lines and you don't even need to switch windows!

But, this isn't quite perfect because wrapped lines tend to mess up a little bit. If your translation wraps over two or three more virtual lines than the original text, the visual correlation fades as the lines aren't one-on-one anymore. I couldn't find a solution or a script for fixing that behavior.

Other suggestion I would propose is to interlace the translation into the original. This approaches the diff method of Benoit's suggestion. After the original is split up into chunks (one chunk per line), I would prepend a `>>` or similar on every line. A translation of one chunk would begin by `o`. The file would look like this:

```
  >> This is an example sentence.
  Tämä on esimerkkilause.
  >> In this format editing is easy.
  Tässä muodossa muokkaaminen on helppoa.
```

And I would enhance the readability by doing a `:match Comment /^>>.*$/` or similar, whatever looks nice with your colorscheme. Probably it would be worthwhile to write a `:syn` region that disables spell checking for the original text. Finally, as a detail, I'd bind `<C-j>` to do `2j` and `<C-k>` to `2k` to allow easy jumping between the parts that matter.

Pros for this latter approach also include that you could wrap things in 80 columns if you feel like I do :) It would still be trivial to write `<C-j/k>` to jump between translations.

Cons: buffer-completion suffers as now it completes both original and translated words. English words don't hopefully occur in the translations that often! :) But this is as robust as it gets. A simple `grep` will peel the original text off after you are done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The `scrollbind`/`cursorbind` idea is a good one, but the other solution seems the most robust. I'm starting with the diff-style method, but I'm still looking into the vsplit version (and it'll be easy to change even in the middle of things).

Comment: There's nothing a quick grep can't do :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a simplified [diff](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Diff) format?

- it is linewise which is suitable for whole sentences.
- The first character is significant (space, special, + or -)
- It will be quite compact
- Maybe you needn't those `@@` parts
- Vim will support it and color the English sentence and the Finnish sentence in distinct colors.

Comment: +1 this sounds like a plausible idea. I'll have to do a little testing too see how it really works out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to keep the 1 - 1 relationship between the original text and the translated text, a database table makes the most sense.

You'd have one table with the following columns:

- id - Integer - Autonum
- original_text - Text - Not null
- translated_text - Text - Nullable

You'd need a process to load the original text, and a process to show you one line of the original text and allow you to type the translated text.  Perhaps the second process could show you 5 lines (2 before, the line you want to translate, and 2 after) to give you context.

Comment: This does solve the problem, but seems cumbersome: I'd have to implement editing software. Editing is certainly not gonna be linear: I'll certainly need to go back and forth. Can you suggest some practical way to implement this, and benefits over my own suggestions? The way I see it, I could almost as well do the translation in Excel...

Comment: I'll also be starting with one big chunk of text, and I'd hope that splitting it into smaller chunks would be easy (which isn't automatically the case with database).

Comment: @dancek: Yes, you have to break the original text in parts.  You can do the editing in any editor you wish.  You just need a couple of GUI's for entering the original text and the translated text.  The database table keeps the pieces of text together.  You can put more than one sentence on each database row, if you wish.  You can use any software that will create CRUD transactions from a database table to create the GUIs.

Comment: Then my workflow would be something like: _split off a chunk, translate, copy original, paste into another window, copy translation, paste into another window, insert both into db_. I guess I could use pgAdmin's data editor, which would be exactly like Excel, and that would save me from jumping window to window. If I split beforehand into chunks of `/[^\n\.]+[\n\.]+/`, it'd be doable (but not as flexible). Or maybe I'll look into connecting Vim straight to the db.