# A vim plugin for translators

Tags: vim, translation

Is there any vim plugin which allows splits for translations. (e.g. 2 vetical splits. one sentence per some block one left side, and mine translated text on right side. and even if translated text bigger than original it will display proper highlighted block on left side)

Comment: If you didn't find anything on [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?order_by=creation_date&direction=descending) the answer is probably "no".

Comment: Slightly related: [Book translation data format](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5485072/659526)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this works for you:

- Use two files, one containing the original texts, one containing the translations.
- Both files have one sentence per line.
- Open both files in a vertically split window (`:vs`).
- Use `:set wrap` to see more lines at a time.
- While still on the first line, enter `:set scrollbind` and `:set cursorbind` in both windows. This will keep both windows in sync when you jump back and forth with the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

There is one new vim plugin: [translate-shell.vim](https://github.com/echuraev/translate-shell.vim). You can try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The [OmegaT](https://omegat.org) free translation memory program now has a Vim mode, through a plugin called [Vimish](https://github.com/npizzigati/vimish). If what you're looking to do is translate texts (or post-edit translations) using familiar Vim keys, this might be worth a look.

Comment: Although tangentially helpful, this doesn't really answer the question - the poster did specifically ask for a vim plugin.